# EXT border layout: error when adding panels

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs

*(EXT 3)* I have moved from an **hbox** layout to a **border** layout. All my components worked fine in the hbox layout (two grids). I've been attempting to add these same items to a border layout and I keep getting an error "comp is undefined". Am I missing something in my panel setup?

```
var skedPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id : 'skedPanel',
        layout : 'border',
    defaults: {
            frame:true,
            split:true
        },
    height:650,
    width: 1200,
    items : [
            {
                region:"east",
                width:300
            },
            {
                region:"center",
                width: 800,
            }

    ]
});
skedPanel.add('center',this.scheduler) < ---- error triggered here
skedPanel.add('east',this.dList1) 
skedPanel.render('root');
```

**EDIT:** Here is the solution to what I wanted to do. First create the regions, then add content. The issue was that the regions were not completely created. Molecule's tip sent me in the right direction.

```
var skedPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id : 'skedPanel',
    layout : 'border',
    defaults: {
            frame:false,
            split:true
        },
    height:650,
    width: 1200,
    items : [
            {
                region:"center",
                id: 'skedCenter',
                width: 850
            },
            {
                region: "east",
                id: 'skedEast',
                width:300
            }

    ]
});

Ext.getCmp('skedCenter').add(this.scheduler)
Ext.getCmp('skedEast').add(this.dList1)
skedPanel.render('root');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have only one 'center' region

Comment: Yes, I only want one. I would like to define it in "items", then load it with content using ".add".

Comment: @Diodeus, as i remember center region must be defined as item of panel before rendering.

Comment: #####Yes, I only want one. I would like to define it in "items", then load it with content using ".add"####### It won't work. Extjs "thinks" you want add one more center region

Comment: I have added a solution to the question.